# How accuratly measure response time in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, response

I have an Express API app like this.

```
var express = require('express');     
const app = express();    
app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
      text: 'my api!' 
  });
 )
});

app.listen(8090, function () {
    console.log('App listening on port 8090');
});
```

I'm wondering what is the most accurate way to measure the response time ?

Comment: This depends on what exactly you mean by 'response time'.

Comment: You mean how long it will take you to respond?

Comment: @MuhandJumah yes I mean the time to respond.

Comment: @estus I mean the time spent since the http request is received by node and the json response is sent out to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution that I found (thanks to [this great tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVAMha41dwo&index=4&list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q)), is to use `morgan`:

```
npm install morgan
```

And then use it in my code like this:

```
const morgan = require('morgan');


app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

Answer (score 9):

You might also want to use the [Performance timing API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_timing_api) in Node (and browsers) to use an API meant explicitly for measuring performance, rather than relying on `Date.` Besides the more semantic API, you can have better resolution, and the API will deal with issues like a "later" call to `Date` returning a value lower than an "earlier" call because someones messed with the system time.

The docs are pretty self-explanatory:

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');
performance.mark('A');
doSomeLongRunningProcess(() => {
    performance.mark('B');
    performance.measure('A to B', 'A', 'B');
    const measure = performance.getEntriesByName('A to B')[0];
    console.log(measure.duration);
    // Prints the number of milliseconds between Mark 'A' and Mark 'B'
});
```

---

OTOH, with regards to performance measurement, and especially latency/duration measurements, it's all in the eyes of the measurer. The most accurate way to do it is to measure in the client code and take into account things like network latency, intermediate processing, framework delays, etc.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Seems like the question you're asking is more like "how to measure the time in my particular code?" rather than looking for accuracy or anything more special.

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64906447/3904109

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are not doing any calculations to check how long it took you to response. Basically you will respond immediately. The right way of doing it if you have something to calculate would be something like this.

```
var express = require('express');     
const app = express();    
app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
  var start = new Date();

  doWork((err) => {
      var end = new Date() - start
      res.status = 200;
      res.end(`It took ${end}ms`);
  })
 )
});

function doWork(callback) {
    // Sleep for 10 seconds
    // This can be any logic, not only sleep (sleep in this case is use
    // to simulate a function that takes long to respond
    setTimeout(function(){callback(null)}, 10000);
}

app.listen(8090, function () {
    console.log('App listening on port 8090');
});
```

You need to know what do you want to do. You can not just measure a request time because request time depends on how long you will take to do your calculations and so if you don't have calculations then there is nothing to take difference of. So with `doWork` I simulated a function that will sleep for 10 seconds. Instead of sleeping you might want to be querying from db or do some heavy math, etc...

Comment: ReferenceError: doWork is not defined

Comment: `doWork` is just a dummy function.. you would have to create it yourself to do any work that needs to be done. This function has a callback in it

Comment: Please provide a complete code. Your snippet also has syntax errors.

Comment: Edited my answer to include example of how `doWork` would look like

Comment: Please give a complete working solution that actually works. not sure how to put your snippets together.

Comment: This is a complete example, I am not sure what you want to do. But give me like 5 minutes and I will write a better example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185654/discussion-between-babr-and-muhand-jumah).

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is already provided by Express and explained in [the reference](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html).

Express uses `debug` package. Debugging can be enabled via `DEBUG` environment variable either globally:

```
process.env.DEBUG = '*';
```

Or for Express router :

```
process.env.DEBUG = 'express:router*';
```

Measured time for each operation is logged in console:

> express:router query  : /api +2ms
>
> express:router expressInit  : /api +1ms

Comment: This line should present in the script, simple as that.

Comment: Well I added `process.env.DEBUG = 'express:router*';` to my code but nothing extra is printed on the console.

Comment: Try to add it as the first line. You can also pass DEBUG as environment variable from shell.

Comment: Well now I get things like `express:router expressInit  : /api +0ms`. Apparently it is not accurate enough to calculate less than milliseconds.

Comment: Were there no `query`? I assume that full request is `query` plus `expressInit`. You didn't define 'accurately' in the question, but I'd say that rounded 0ms is nitpicking. This route really takes virtually no time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185692/discussion-between-babr-and-estus).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution using only node js:

```
const { performance } = require("perf_hooks");

const t0 = performance.now();
// your code
const t1 = performance.now();
```

time  of execution = t1 - t0 (in ms)