# How to calculate the query execution time in node.js?

Tags: javascript

How to calculate query Execution time in mysql using node.js as back end ?

SET profiling = 1;
SHOW PROFILES;

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141129/nodejs-mysql-measure-query-execution-time. Check this